# How can we handle the Java ConcurrentModificationException using try-catch?

Tags: java, exception, collections, concurrentmodification, fail-fast

I am trying to handle the java ConcurrentModificationException exception using try-catch block but still I am getting the same error when compiling the code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class failFast{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(100,"Melani");
        map.put(101,"Harshika");
        map.put(102,"Nimna");

        Iterator itr = map.keySet().iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());

            try{
                map.put(103,"Nirmani");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception is thrown "+e);
            }
            
        }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at failFast.main(failFast.java:12)
```

Comment: Because it's thrown on this line: `System.out.println(itr.next());`... As clearly shown on the stack trace.

Comment: You don't fix coding bugs with exception handlers. You fix the bugs. The concurrent modification is being performed by *this code.* You must do the add via the iterator, not via the `map` you are iterating.

Comment: @user207421 The general `Iterator` doesn't have an `add` method, only `ListIterator` does.

Comment: To fix, use `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @Andreas suggesting `ConcurrentHashMap` is a bad advice as it implies keeping the broken logic. There’s no sense in doing `map.put(103,"Nirmani");` multiple times within a loop. While this is only an example, chances are high that the real life case also should be fixed by changing the program logic rather than resorting to `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now exactly what you are trying to achive (your code doesn't make much sense for me). Basically you can't change a `Map` or an other `Collection` while iterating over it. The only way to change the underlying structure is with the actual `Iterator` but this is very limited. To catch the `ConcurrentModificationException` makes not much sense because with your code it will always be thrown, so the catch-block would be your normal code flow, which is really not good.

**Possibility 1:** Copy `keySet` to an other collection and iterate over this one

```
import java.util.*;
public class FailFast{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(100,"Melani");
        map.put(101,"Harshika");
        map.put(102,"Nimna");

        // Copy keySet to an other collection and iterate over this one
        Iterator itr = new ArrayList(map.keySet()).iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
            map.put(103,"Nirmani");            
        }
```

**Possibility 2:** Collect all the changes and apply them after the loop (this is what I would do)

```
import java.util.*;
public class FailFast{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(100,"Melani");
        map.put(101,"Harshika");
        map.put(102,"Nimna");

        Iterator itr = map.keySet().iterator();

        Map<Integer,String> changes = new HashMap<>();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
            changes.put(103,"Nirmani");            
        }
        map.putAll(changes);
```